# Error trying to get data using XPath on Google IMPORTXML function

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to find the XPath to get 5 values of the following website: https://plataforma.penserico.com/dashboard/cp.pr?e=TRPL4

I want the values `7,59` `2,04` `1,81` `7,60` `7,59`

For the first value I tried this command but I get #N/A:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://plataforma.penserico.com/dashboard/cp.pr?e=TRPL4";"//*[@id='j_idt104:0:j_idt109:1:chartPanel0']/div/span[1]")
```

The piece of HTML is like below:

```html
<span id="j_idt104:0:j_idt109:1:chartPanel0">
<div class="c--anim-btn" style="color: #5DADE2;">
<span class="c-anim-btn">
7,59
</span>
<span>
<div style="font-size: 12px !important;">
<div style="width: 90%; left: 5%; position:relative;line-height:2em;white-space: nowrap;">
<div style="width:50%;float:left"><label class="idtri">1T:</label>2,04</div>
<div style="width:50%;float:right"><label class="idtri">2T:</label>1,81</div>
</div>
<div style="width: 90%; left: 5%; position:relative;line-height:2em;white-space: nowrap;">
<div style="width:50%;float:left"><label class="idtri">3T:</label>7,60</div>
<div style="width:50%;float:right"><label class="idtri">4T:</label>7,59</div>
</div>
</div>
</span>
</div></span>
```

What could be the second paramenter to get the values I want?
Thank you

Comment: none. GS does not support importing from JavaScripted sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix your XPath with the following one to get the values :

```
//tr[.//span[.='P/L']]/td[2]//text()[parent::span[@class='c-anim-btn'] or parent::div][normalize-space()]
```

Output (formula in C4):

[image: Values]

EDIT : Individual XPath :

```
//tr[.//span[.='P/L']]/td[2]//text()[parent::span[@class='c-anim-btn']]
(//tr[.//span[.='P/L']]/td[2]//text()[parent::div][normalize-space()])[1]
(//tr[.//span[.='P/L']]/td[2]//text()[parent::div][normalize-space()])[2]
(//tr[.//span[.='P/L']]/td[2]//text()[parent::div][normalize-space()])[3]
(//tr[.//span[.='P/L']]/td[2]//text()[parent::div][normalize-space()])[4]
```

Comment: Great, this command brings all the values I want. Thank you.
One more thing: is there a way to get each value at a time? I think it would be 5 different XPath commands, right?!

Comment: Exactly. I've added them in my post. Please mark my answer as accepted if your problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you very much!